# Cannot resolve method 'makeRestartActivityTask(android.content.ComponentName)'

Tags: java, android

Обновил версии в build.gradle до 27:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
// и т.д.
```

Синхронизировалось нормально, но вот только теперь в Reciver, в строке:

```
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(komponent);
```

пишется:

> Cannot resolve method
>   'makeRestartActivityTask(android.content.ComponentName)'

**Вопрос:** Как resolve метод 'makeRestartActivityTask'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google удалил метод `IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask()` в текущей версии поддержки. Вместо этого вы можете просто использовать Android API:

```
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
```

UPDATE:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/27.0.0/changes/android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat

Comment: Ошибки не возникает. Вроде работает.
Не могли бы вы подкрепить ваш комментарий каким-нибудь доказательством? Почему-то моих способностей не хватает найти какое-нибудь свидетельство, что Google удалил метод IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask() в текущей версии поддержки.

Comment: Добавил ссылку в ответ